# Unnecessary large white margin for graph with bezier curve

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

Compare following visualizations of two simple graphs in Mathematica 11.2:

#### K3 `Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}]`

[image]

#### Two-edge multi graph `Graph[{1 -> 1, 1 -> 1}]`

(try also three-edge multi graph `Graph[{1 -> 1, 1 -> 1, 1-> 1}]`) :

[image]

In the second case Mathematica adds unnecessary large margins to all sides. Is there a generic fix for this. I draw many graphs and do not want to adjust this manually.

Comment: noting that `PlotRangePadding` works with `Graph` but is ignored in the case of a single-node graph I think this could be labeled as a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help from kglr (deleted comment):

```
Graphics[Show[Graph[{1 -> 1, 1 -> 1}]][[1]]]
```

[image]

which works by using `Show` to convert the graph to a `Graphics[]` object, and then constructing a new graphic using only the primitives and directives, but none of the options.

In this case `PlotRangePadding` is the option that causes the extra space, so using something like

```
Graph[{1 -> 1, 1 -> 1, 1 -> 1}, PlotRange -> 0]
```

or

```
Show[Graph[{1 -> 1, 1 -> 1}], PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

will only affect that particular option.

Answer (score 6):

Another work around, adding a dummy vertex at the same coordinate seems to make things happy.

```
Graph[{1, 2}, {1 -> 1, 1 -> 1, 1 -> 1}, 
 VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}]
```

try also:

```
Graph[{1 -> 1, 1 -> 1, 1 -> 1}, PlotRange -> 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the figure and there is a 'Make standard size' function at the bottom.
According to the documentation, there seems to be no way to do it programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know how to do this automatically and not using the mouse?

Comment: No according to the document...

Comment: This does not do what the OP asks. It resets the figure size. It does not change the plot range or margins.